# How to install fiddler on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, web-development

Could anybody show me how to install [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) on Ubuntu? I need to use it for web development.

Comment: What is "fiddler"? It's not a Ubuntu package. Is there a `.deb` available? Does the "fiddler" website mention Linux?

Comment: fiddler is a web debugging tool and it is not a ubuntu package. As far as I know, fiddler is indeed supported by linux.

Comment: Is it the telerik version?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First things first:

1. Install `mono`:

   ```
    sudo apt install mono-complete
   ```
2. Download `fiddler` for Linux by clicking [here](http://www.telerik.com/docs/default-source/fiddler/fiddler-linux.zip?sfvrsn=2) and extract it.
3. Then with mono installed run it with from the extracted directory:

   ```
    mono Fiddler.exe
   ```
4. Or run with `mono /path/to/extracted/fiddler/Fiddler.exe`

[image]

Source:

https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono

#### UPDATE

The fiddler can be gotten from [here](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-everywhere) and installed using the following commands:

1. `chmod a+x progress-telerik-fiddler.AppImage`, to make the installer executable, and,
2. `./progress-telerik-fiddler.AppImage`: to install the fiddler.

Comment: Does not work. Getting this error and Fiddler is crashing. [1]    8102 abort (core dumped)  mono /home/curtis/Desktop/vjbl/fiddler-linux/Fiddler.exe
Unable to attach: program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.                                                                                      
No threads.

Comment: @George Udosen You should probably update your answer. The version of Fiddler you linked is way outdated (2017). The new way to run Fiddler on Linux is by downloading the AppImage: https://telerik-fiddler.s3.amazonaws.com/fiddler-latest/progress-telerik-fiddler.AppImage You can then you run `./fiddler.AppImage` instead of `mono fiddler.exe`.

Comment: @forivin thanks will do that once I switch to my Ubuntu OS!

Comment: Maybe is better to remove the old solution, or at least put the new first and the old later!

Comment: Old method does not work now, but new fiddler appimage seems much less functional, so let it be. `mono FiddlerSetup.exe 
Cannot open assembly 'FiddlerSetup.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.`

Answer (score 7):

To install Fiddler on Ubuntu, use this link [Fiddler Everywhere](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere). You will be directed to download the AppImage file. Once the AppImage file is downloaded, the only thing you require is to make it executable by changing its permissions (*Right-click on the file and selected properties. On the permissions tab, select **Allow executing the file as program***). To run the application, right-click on the file and select Run.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler develop for Mono framework.

1. Add the Mono repository to your system http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin
2. Download Fiddler for linux https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler
3. Extract archive with Fiddler and run Fiddler.exe (press right button and run with Mono)